# как создать множество обьектов в канвасе?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Разрабатываю 2д игруху и не пойму как реализовать одну функцию...
я создаю множество объектов монеток,как их всех запихнуть в канвас,а после дать обьектам монеток координаты и размер?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081133/adding-child-image-to-canvas-with-settings-in-wpf-c-sharp

Comment: создаешь префаб на канвасе, так его и сохраняешь. после просто инстанциируешь объект и задаешь `anchoredPosition` по x/y. вроде способ ничем не отличается от создания объекта не на канвасе. создаешь объект если что как `Instantiate(coinPrefab, parent)`, где parent - объект типа Transform

Comment: канвас не предназначен для реализации игровой логики.